# How can I use clSetKernelArg to set local memory size in an OpenCL Haskell program?

Tags: haskell, opencl, ffi

I'm using the `System.GPU.OpenCL` module by Luis Cabellos to control an OpenCL kernel.
All is working well but to speed things up I am trying to cache some global memory into a local buffer.  I have just noticed that it seems to be impossible to pass a local buffer using the current definition of `clSetKernelArg`, but perhaps someone can enlighten me?

The definition is,

```
clSetKernelArg :: Storable a => CLKernel -> CLuint -> a -> IO ()
clSetKernelArg krn idx val = with val $ \pval -> do
  whenSuccess (raw_clSetKernelArg krn idx (fromIntegral . sizeOf $ val) (castPtr pval))
    $ return ()
```

where the raw function is defined as,

```
foreign import CALLCONV "clSetKernelArg" raw_clSetKernelArg ::
  CLKernel -> CLuint -> CSize -> Ptr () -> IO CLint
```

Therefore the high level `clSetKernelArg` conveniently figures out the size of the memory and also extracts a pointer to it.  This is perfect for global memory, but it seems that the way to use `clSetKernelArg` when local memory is requested is to specify the size of the desired memory in the `CSize`, and set `Ptr` to zero.  Of course, putting `nullPtr` here doesn't work, so how can I circumvent this problem?  I would call `raw_clSetKernelArg` directly, but it seems it is not exported by the module.

Thanks.

Comment: Looking at the OpenCL documentation it seems that you are correct that when the object is local that the pointer should be NULL.  Why doesn't nullPtr work?

Comment: @vivian: Because the exported `clSetKernelArg` interface doesn't let you specify your own pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's any way to rig up a hack so that `pval` ends up being a `nullPtr`.

This seems like a fairly simple omission from the wrapped API; I'd suggest simply [reporting it](https://github.com/zhensydow/opencl/issues) rather than trying to hack around it :)

Comment: `clSetKernelArg :: Storable a => CLKernel -> CLuint -> Maybe a -> IO ()` would do the trick.

Comment: @vivian: It seems the functionality has [already been added](https://github.com/zhensydow/opencl/issues/22) :)